# Problem sending emails with sendmail and mutt through gmail

Tags: sendmail, mutt

I can send emails as root and when I go into mutt as root it connects to gmail's smtp servers but if I am a normal user (in this case Nagios) it does not connect to gmail's smtp server and will try to send it as nagios@sendemail@gmail.com instead of the sendmail@gmail.com account I have set up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried running mutt as nagios with sudo and then it did root@sendmail@gmail.com. It only puts the user in the front with user accounts not with root account and only when I use root outside of sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is highly vague, so I can only estimate that it is something that can be solved by properly setting up ~nagios/.muttrc so that the sender's email address is sendmail@gmail.com:

```
my_hdr From: "Name Here" <sendmail@gmail.com>
```

Again this holds if I understand what you're asking.